# Convert Kibana query (create index pattern) to Python request

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to convert this Kibana query to Python:

```
PUT /.kibana/_doc/index-pattern:tempindex
{
  "type": "index-pattern",
  "index-pattern": {
    "title": "tempindex",
    "timeFieldName": "sendTime"
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

uri = "http://localhost:5601/_doc/index-pattern:tempindex"

query = json.dumps({
  "type": "index-pattern",
  "index-pattern": {
    "title": "tempindex",
    "timeFieldName": "sendTime"
  }
})

r = requests.put(uri, headers=HEADERS, data=query).json()
print(r)
```

But it gives me

```
{'statusCode': 404, 'error': 'Not Found', 'message': 'Not Found'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: Both Elastic and Kibana servers are local (Windows 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that just changing the `uri` does the trick:

```
uri = "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/_doc/index-pattern:tempindex"
```

But I'm not sure about the `HEADERS`, cuz as [lupanoide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5362842/lupanoide) pointed out, `kbn-xsrf: true` should be present, but either way it seems to be working and apparently the results are the same (I haven't spotted a difference yet).

Edit: As the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-api.html#api-request-headers) says:

> `kbn-xsrf: true`
>
> By default, you must use `kbn-xsrf` for all API calls, except in the
> following scenarios:
>
> The API endpoint uses the `GET` or `HEAD` operations
> The path is whitelisted using the [server.xsrf.whitelist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) setting
> XSRF protections are disabled using the `server.xsrf.disableProtection` setting

So I think it should be present.

Comment: that header should be present for the other API, the kibana one. However elastic says that write directly to the .kibana index makes the data corrupted and permanently breaks future Kibana versions https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/dashboard-api.html Good luck!!

Comment: That's why I said it "seems" to be working. Thank you.